# SQL select all items of an owner from an item-to-owner table

Tags: select, mysql

I have a table bike_to_owner. I would like to select current items owned by a specific user.

Table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bike_to_owner` (
  `bike_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `last_change_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`bike_id`,`user_id`,`last_change_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

In the profile page of the user I would like to display all his/her current possessions.

I wrote this statement:

```
SELECT `bike_id`,`user_id`,max(last_change_date) FROM `bike_to_owner` 
WHERE `user_id` = 3 group by `last_change_date`
```

but i'm not quite sure it works correctly in all cases.
Can you please verify this is correct and if not suggest me something better.
Using php/mysql.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on discussion under Eric's answer, can you provide some sample data and a sample of what you want the data returned by the query to look like?

Comment: Seconding Philip's comment.  If you provide some sample data where the answer I provided doesn't give the correct result, and what you would expect the correct result to be, we could probably help you a bit better.

Comment: Ok here is some sample data.

INSERT INTO `bike_to_owner` (`bike_id`, `user_id`, `last_change_date`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2009-01-01'),
(1, 3, '2009-11-10'),
(3, 3, '2009-02-13'),
(3, 5, '2010-05-11'),
(5, 5, '2010-06-04');

I would expect user 1 to own only bike 1, user 1 not to have bikes at all and user 5 to own bikes 3 and 5.

Comment: @Eric:
The statement you proposed returns:

bike_id  user_id  max(last_change_date)
1          1          2009-01-01

when run for user 1

 bike_id  user_id  max(last_change_date)
1                 3  2009-11-10
3                 3  2009-02-13

when run for user 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of your comments, I'm going to just give a new answer here.

Since you could have a user taking ownership of a bike, then giving it up, then getting it back again and you want to be able to track that history, I would suggest a slight change to your schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bike_to_owner` (
  `bike_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `acquired_date` date NOT NULL,
  `sold_date` date NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`bike_id`,`user_id`,`acquired_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Whenever a bike changes hands, you would update the `sold_date` for the previous owner to the current date and create a new record for the new owner with a `sold_date` of NULL and an `acquired_date` of the current date.

Then your query to determine current ownership would look like this:

```
SELECT `bike_id`,`user_id` FROM `bike_to_owner` 
WHERE `user_id` = 3 AND sold_date IS NULL
```

Comment: You have a point. Your way on the other hand makes the database not normalized because every `sold_date` will be new the owner's `acquired_date`. The select statement is 2143232523542 times simpler, though.

So which is better? I would stick to my previous design in order not to make other changes in the code i have already written, but if you have some strong arguments I'll make the change.

Comment: @kdobrev - I wouldn't say it isn't normalized.  This is a very common pattern.  It also allows for the concept of a person selling a bike to someone who isn't a user (or a bike being stolen or destroyed for example).  With your current model the only way to stop owning a bike is to sell it to another user.  If you are concerned about it though, you could replace `sold_date` with an `active` or `current` bit column and use it the same way.  Using `sold_date` provides more information than a bit column though and makes other potential queries much easier.

Comment: My model tracks transactions, while this model tracks the relationships (over time) between User and Bike. Either model works. The final model you use is based on the known (and anticipated) requirements of the system you are building.

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, but you should be grouping by bike_id and user_id rather than last change date:

```
SELECT `bike_id`,`user_id`,max(last_change_date) FROM `bike_to_owner` 
WHERE `user_id` = 3 group by `bike_id`, `user_id`
```

ETA:

As an aside, I'm curious why you have the last change date in that table as part of the key.  Would it be possible for a bike to be associated with a user multiple times with different change dates?  If so, why?  I would think that a bike is either associated with a user or not associated with a user - there's really nothing that could "change" there aside from the relationship being added or deleted.  Unless there are other fields on that table that you aren't showing?

Comment: First to answer your question. This is for a bike register. So bikes are real world bikes and users are real people. People sell their bike to each other and the bikes stays the same in the system. So the owner changes, not more often than once per day. There is a minimal chance somebody to buy off their old, previously sold, bike . The table structure shown is the whole table, no more fields.

Unfortunately both statements, mine and Eric's, do not return the correct values.

Comment: I do not insist for this table structure, it's just how I thought it would be best. If you can suggest something better I would be happy to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the statement that works:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM bike_to_owner t1
LEFT JOIN bike_to_owner AS t2 ON t1.bike_id = t2.bike_id
AND t1.last_change_date < t2.last_change_date
WHERE t2.last_change_date IS NULL
AND t1.user_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot depends on what information you are trying to store and be able to retrieve from the database. Attempting to second-guess this, I’d propose the following set of tables (and note that only the one column in any of these tables allow nulls):

```
--  User  -----
user_id  (primary key)
name

--  Bike  ------
bike_id  (primary key)
description
current_owner  nullable  (foreign key to User)
```

This presumes that “bike ownership” is a criticial and frequently desired piece of information, and is worth adding denormalized data to the structure to make finding a bike’s current user or a user’s current bikes trivial. (A key reason for adding denormalized data is to simplify data retrieval and/or improve performance. Skipping working out sales history on every query you make does both.) If duration of ownership is important, a column for “purchased_on” could be added, or you delve into the transaction tables.

To track when bikes were purchased:

```
--  Bike_Purchase   ------
user_id  (foreign key to User)
bike_id  (foreign key to Bike)
purchased_on
(primary key on all three columns)
```

would track every time a user purchased a bike. If instead you’d rather track when a bike was sold, you could have

```
--  Bike_Sale   ------
user_id  (foreign key to User)
bike_id  (foreign key to Bike)
sold_on
(primary key on all three columns)
```

To track both purchases and sales, include either both tables or a simple conglomerate:

```
--  Bike_Transaction   ------
user_id  (foreign key to User)
bike_id  (foreign key to Bike)
transaction_type  **
transaction_date
(primary key on all four columns)
```

This allows you to accurately track purchases and sales for your users, and disregard transactions by non-users. Sold a bike? Make an entry. Don’t know or care who they sold it to? Don’t make an entry.

Whichever time-tracking table you use, determining duration of ownership is as simple as joining on (user_id, bike_id) and getting max(date). Piecing together the “ownership chain” of a given bike, or what bikes a user owned and when/for how long would be tricky, but entirely doable.

** For transaction_type, you may need to set up a Transaction_Type table to track the different transactions (sold, purchased, traded, found, lost/stolen, etc. etc.) Alternatively, you could make it a varchar containing a descriptive string, or put a CHECK constraint to limit it to selected values.